# ADAL - Error calling AuthenticationContext in javascript app

Tags: javascript, azure, adal

I´m getting an error when I call AuthenticationContext method from my windows store app HTML/Javascript.

The code is the next:

`var adal = Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
var authcontext2 = new adal.AuthenticationContext(audience);`

and the error I'm getting is:

**0x80040154 - JavaScript runtime error: Class not registered**

Any clue how to solve this?

I'm using v2.6 of Microsoft.Identity.Model.Clients.ActiveDirectory added with nuget.

I think that the error started to happen wwhen I deleted the old version of AAL.

Thanks,

SOLVED: I had recently updated VS2013 to update 4, after some reading I tried updating again, in this case to Update 5RC, and that did the trick.

Comment: Did you update the VS version recently? what version are you on?

Comment: Yes, I updated VS2013 to Update 4. I have solved the issue updating again to update 5RC. I suppose there is a bug or the update causes some problems with the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem.

I had recently updated VS2013 to update 4, that could have been part of the problem. After some reading I tried updating again, in this case to Update 5RC, and that did the trick.

Now it works.

Thks